# Conditions in underscore.js templates

Tags: templates, underscore.js

How can we check a condition in underscore and print accordingly?

Sample code.

```
<%  if(status==1){  %>
<%= status %>
<% } %>
```

Is there a way to remove the overlapping %> and <%= ??

I am a php developer and the above code in php would be :

```
<?php
if($status==1){
 echo $status;
}
?>
```

Is there a way to echo in underscore like "echo"?

Comment: Have you read http://underscorejs.org/#template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, try with `print();`

like:

```
<% if(status===1) {
    print(status);
} %>
```

docs: http://underscorejs.org/#template